# Previous Android Response Being Added to Status Line

Tags: android, android-networking, android-volley

I'm using Volley to communicate with an API.

I am sending a request and on success of that request I *immediately* fire off another one, using the same message queue.

The issue I have is the second request is responding with the following error:

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: {"id":47}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

The `{"id":47}` is the response body from the first request. I'm not even going near the status line in my code and the requests are fairly simple.

What on earth is happening?! Is it a bug within Volley?

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose that the status line `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"` is expected to be before the actual response content `{"id":47}` - according to the error message it seems to be exactly reversed.

Comment: Well the status should be just `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, the `{"id":47}` is the body from the _previous_ request response.

Comment: Sorry, I have read over that. That is a strange bug, indeed. I have had a short look in the Implementation of Volley to trace the StatusLine and the part where the response is fetched but could not see any obvious problems here which could cause this particular problem... It is possible, that it could be also a problem of the API itself?

Comment: I had thought that but the API works as expected and there's no issue with other applications.

Comment: @Flixer: Is there any fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the server return content when status code is `204`,

api should not return data when 204 responses